# how to reduce a 3 dim numpy array to 2 dim

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to reduce a 3 dim numpy array into a 2 dim array but can't think of a way other than putting it in a for loop and that takes way too much time. below is my code snippet. train_dataset is a 3 dimensional array of shape (200000,28,28) and I want to convert it into a 2 dim array of shape (5600000,28) by stacking each of the 28 x 28 array 200,000 times. But the below code takes way too much time. can someone pls advice

```
train_data = np.empty([28,28])
for i in range(train_dataset.shape[0]):
     train_data=np.append(train_data,train_dataset[i,:,:],axis=0)
```

Comment: that's not even the same number of elements. 200000*28*28 > 4800000*28

Comment: corrected it. apologies..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the reshape function that provides reshaping of array in one predefined shape to another array with given dimension.
**Example:**

train_data = numpy.reshape(train_dataset,(4800000, 28))

I guess that will do the job.

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to stack along `axis=0`, which means the order of data doesn't change, you can simply reshape it keeping the size of the last dimension the same:

```
train_dataset.reshape(-1, train_dataset.shape[-1])
```

*Example*:

```
train_dataset = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]]])

train_dataset
#array([[[1, 2],
#        [3, 4]],

#       [[5, 6],
#        [7, 8]]])

train_dataset.reshape(-1, train_dataset.shape[-1])
#array([[1, 2],
#       [3, 4],
#       [5, 6],
#       [7, 8]])
```

Comment: thanks. what does the -1 (the 1st parameter in the reshape method) do?

Comment: -1 means the size of the first dimension *is inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions* which in your case would be `200000*28`, since the last dimension is specified as `28`.